# Redefinition of complement set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I read on nLab this idea of 'complement' set

> The **complement** $\tilde S$ of a subset $S$ of a set $X$ is the set of all elements of $X$ not contained in $S$: 
>  
>   $\tilde{S} = \{ a: X \;|\; a \notin S \}$

I don't like the underlying message, I prefer rewrite this definition as

> The **complement** $\tilde S$ of a subset $S$ of a set $X$ is the set of all elements of $X$ *that complete* $X$: 
>  
>   $\tilde{S} = \{ a: X \;|\; a \supseteq X$ }

The question is this: what do you think ?

Comment: Your purported definition of the *complement* is : "the set of all elements $a$ of $X$ such that $X$ is a subset of $a$". It does not work.

Comment: Let $X = \{ 1,2,3 \}$ and $S= \{ 1,2 \}$. There are no $a \in X$ such that $X \subseteq a$ but the complemet of $S$ (relative to $X$) is $\{ 3 \}$.

Comment: An element of $X$ can't contain $X$. Your second definition leads to $\tilde{S} = \emptyset$.

Comment: The "traditional" def od *compement* is simple and easy to use and we are quite happy with it.

Comment: What do you mean with $a:X$ in $\{a:X\mid a\notin S\}$? I never met this notation.

Comment: Maybe you have to work on the idea of "completing" $S$ in $X$ (and not $X$), that means that the complement of $S$ in $X$ is the set of those elements of $X$ that belongs to $X \setminus S$. But to say that $a \in (X \setminus S)$ means exactly : $a \in X \text { and } a \notin S$ and thus we arrive at the usual def : $\overline S = \{ a \mid a \in X \text { and } a \notin S \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA , in symbols how you write *the set of those elements of $X$ that belongs to $X \setminus S$* ?

Comment: I've written it in the comment above.

Comment: Ah, ok, you rewrite same definition but in other way

Comment: You talk about $X \setminus S$ as *quotient* set as idea of a completing of $S$ in $X$ ? So you're proposing to "divide" a set $X$ by $S\subseteq X$, wherein you set all elements of $S$ to the identity in $X$ ?